# How to install npm pckage from private git repoistory using a token in github actions

Tags: node.js, docker, github, npm, github-actions

I'm trying to install npm packages for my application within a Dockerfile. However, I get the following error when it comes to installing a package from a private git repository.

```
 Step 9/10 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in 57960fe4df81
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ***github.com/<redacted-private-org>/<redacted-private-repo>.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! remote: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<redacted-private-org>/<redacted-private-repo>.git/' not found
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.18.0-alpine3.10

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh

RUN mkdir -p /home/dev

WORKDIR /home/dev

COPY . /home/dev

RUN npm ci

CMD ["node", "api/api.js"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "me",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./api/server.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "org-common-utils": "git+https://<redacted-username>:<redacted-token>@github.com/<redacted-private-org>/<redacted-private-repo>.git",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-routes-mapper": "^1.1.0",
    "helmet": "^3.12.0",
    "igdb-api-node": "^3.1.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.4",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.3",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "shx": "^0.2.2",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

To install from a private Github repository I'm using a username and token combination as you can see in my package.json.

The repository exists because if I try to navigate to the URL it loads when I'm logged in 
https://github.com/redacted-private-org/redacted-private-repo

This issue is only occurring in github actions pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was only occurring in github actions pipeline. It's solved by setting `persist-credentials` to false otherwise it uses github actions token which does not have the necessary permissions to pull/install the repository.
.

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@master
  with:
    persist-credentials: false
```

https://github.com/actions/checkout

Comment: alternatively, we can use SSH to install the private repo with github ssh action.