# In a Github Action how to publish a private package to NPM that uses private dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

Trying to figure out how in a Github organization using a private org's dependency (this case a private NPM package) and publish a new private package with a Github Action but it errors in Actions:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@wilson%monday - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@wilson/monday@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'tuesday'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

My *npm.yml* file:

```
name: npm
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm ci --ignore-scripts
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          CI: true
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

I've also tried changing `registry-url` to:

```
registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
```

*package.json*:

```
  "name": "@wilson/tuesday",
  "version": "1.3.7"
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted",
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/wilson/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wilson/monday": "latest",
  },
```

Closest question I could find pertaining to this: "[How can I publish a private github package with github actions inside a private organization repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941026/how-can-i-publish-a-private-github-package-with-github-actions-inside-a-private)".

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931356/1952287) I'm assuming I do not need an .npmrc in my repository.

Further research on the topic:

- [Install private github package from package.json on Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614077/install-private-github-package-from-package-json-on-github-actions)
- [Github Actions workflow (private repo) hangs when trying to publish to packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548344/github-actions-workflow-private-repo-hangs-when-trying-to-publish-to-packages)
- [How to install npm pckage from private git repoistory using a token in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407913/how-to-install-npm-pckage-from-private-git-repoistory-using-a-token-in-github-ac)
- [Github actions, 401 unauthorized when installing a Github Package with npm or yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124831/github-actions-401-unauthorized-when-installing-a-github-package-with-npm-or-ya)

In my Github Action how can I publish a private package to NPM that uses a private dependency?

Comment: Don't you need to authenticate for the `npm install` call?

Comment: That is what I thought and thought it's why I needed .npmrc but from my research if i understand correctly that is what is enabled in Github's personal access tokens under `write:packages` and why I needed `"registry"` in *package.json*.

Comment: Any updates on that one ?